# android -No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'

Tags: android

I've downloaded the latest appcompact version . this is my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.navid.recycleview"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

in the sdk manager , I've downloaded sdk platform and google apis for both api23 and 21 .

When I rebuild the project ,it opens v21\values-v21.xml and there are lots of error in this file :

```
    F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v17\values-v17.xml
Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(17, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginEnd'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(23, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
Error:(26, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
Error:(10, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
Error:(13, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
Error:(26, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
Error:(37, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(40, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
Error:(44, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
Error:(37, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
Error:(23, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(128, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(126, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(125, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(131, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(128, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(126, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(125, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
Error:(131, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
Error:(217, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
Error:(217, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
Error:(124, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
Error:(128, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'.
Error:(126, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
Error:(127, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
Error:(125, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
Error:(123, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
F:\AndroidStudioProjects\recycleView\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.0\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(1) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

What is the problem ? How can I fix it ?

thanks

Comment: You need to use target sdk version 23 in order to use that style.  Let me guess, Android Studio 1.3.1....

Answer (score 6):

To use features provided by API 21 you should specify corresponding value for parameter compileSdkVersion:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    ...
```

Attribute android:targetSdkVersion just informs the system that you have tested against the target version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version. A more detailed description you can get in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the appcompat to other version.

example:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}
```